# Where does Maven get the values of variables surrounded by ${}?

Tags: java, xml, maven

I often see something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Where exactly does Maven get the value of `org.springframework.version` from? Does it mean the latest version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a reference to a property. It might be defined in the same pom like for example with:

```
<properties>
  <org.springframework.version>a.b.c</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
```

If you do not find it in the pom.xml, check parent poms, it might be defined there.